# How to rename the "Personal folder" link in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles, user-folders

I added my "Personal folder" (what Windows 10 calls the user folder that takes your name) to my Start menu from the settings. Unfortunately, while clicking on that Start menu entry goes to my user folder (that is, `D:\Users\Hashim`), in the menu itself it's just called "Personal folder". (As an odd aside, the menu item at the top that *does* have the full name of my user account doesn't go to any link at all, but merely user account settings and sign out options.)

How can I rename the "Personal folder" in Windows 10's Start menu to be the actual name of my users folder, as was the case in Windows 7?

[image]

Comment: When I obtain the screen you have above (which is above the Start button), my personal file has my Name on it (not "personal folder" and the name is my Name as shows in My Account (Settings, Accounts)

Comment: @John Are you sure you're referring to the "Personal folder" link and not the account settings link? If you right click on the menu and select "Personalise this list", is the "Personal folder" toggle in that Settings window enabled?

Comment: My list (same as yours above) shows my name and when I right click on it, it points me to Account Settings (as one option) so yes, Personal Folders is in another location and not normally in your list above.

Comment: If you wish easy access to Personal Folders, make sure it is on your Desktop, and then add the Desktop Toolbar (lower right).  Personal Folders (again with my Name on it) becomes an easy access flyout.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. When you right click on the left side of the Start menu and click on "Personalise this list" and then enable the "Personal folder" toggle in the window that appears, is the new menu item in the Start menu called "Personal folder" (as in my screenshot) or does it have your name?

Comment: I use Windows in a very standard way and Personal Folders  (by that name) is not an option on that list. Documents is there (your list and mine) and otherwise my Account name is there. Personal Folders goes on and is accessible on the Desktop with easy access.